# Why does my battery have different charge rates?

Tags: power-management, battery

I do hope my question does not sound too silly, of course, YMMV, but I can get different rates within seconds just by unplugging/plugging the charger, without altering any running processes, from a rate of 0 to 17.5w, the rate is all over the map. If I don't like the rate, say 3.7w, I just plug/unplug the charger a few times until I see a satisfactory rate. But then, is that the real rate? Perhaps my laptop is sending bogus info. I guess I need battery enlightenment. Here is some basic info:

```
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               Notebook
  model:                BAT
  serial:               0001
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sat 09 Jan 2021 06:44:53 PM MST (52 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              5.757 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         32.7978 Wh
    energy-full-design:  36.48 Wh
    energy-rate:         15.8346 W
    voltage:             11.616 V
    time to full:        1.7 hours
    percentage:          17%
    capacity:            89.9062%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-low-charging-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1610243093  17.000  charging
  History (rate):
    1610243093  15.835  charging
```

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.10 x86_64
Host: N141CU
Kernel: Linux 5.8.0-34-generic
Uptime: 14m 
Packages: 1755 (dpkg), 8 (snap)
Shell: /bin/bash 5.0.17
Resolution: 1920x1080 @ 60.00Hz
DE: GNOME 3.38.1
WM: Mutter
WM Theme: Adwaita
Theme: Yaru-dark 
Icons: ubuntu-mono-light
Terminal: gnome-terminal
CPU: Intel i7-10510U (8) @ 4.900GHz [44.0°C]
GPU: Intel UHD Graphics
Memory: 2.80GiB / 15.33GiB (18%)
```

Comment: Background processes can cause this. Your SSD will draw additional power when reading and twice as much when writing. Caches are flushed when needed, at non-regular intervals. The CPU will cycle up and down. Devices will be polled for status information. Modern operating systems are quite busy even when we are not interacting with them.

Answer (score 1):

This is more generic answer but you'd figure out the reason.

1. The life of the battery largely varies based on how we use it.
2. When you use, charge fully and unplug until it discharges till 10% then plug it again. This kind of usage will give you optimal battery life.
3. Average battery life is 3-4 years. Then you'll see sudden dip in the overall capacity hence the shorter discharge period. This means, the battery is loosing it's energy and needs replacement.
4. When you see this behaviour get a new battery as soon as possible. When I say as soon as possible. I really mean it because it's really tough to get a genuine battery after 4-5 years since the product was launched.
5. Manufacturers can't make batteries and keep them in shelf for ever, also they want the consumers to buy a new machine. It's a mix of marketing as well as technical challenge.

Now coming to your issue

1. Check the value of energy-full-design
2. Check the value of energy-full
3. For the brand new battery this will be almost identical but you'll hardly see exact match. But that's fine.
4. If there is a noticeable difference, which means some cells are dead and total capacity is reduced.
5. energy-full-design is static which means the model is designed to be having the specified capacity.
6. Other values are calculated by kernel communicating with the battery firmware.
7. If you correlate my above statements, you can see that the capacity is now 89.9062% which is directly proportional to energy-full.

So as per the statistics, your device's battery has 10% less capacity than it was in the beginning. But the discharging rates can vary. Kernel has some impact on these values. For example, how it controls the power usage of the machine like Optimal, Battery saver, Full power etc.

If your battery is behaving normally in use not going by the statistics, I think you're OK with the current situation. But sudden changes in battery percentage like from 80-70 in a few seconds can be problematic. Then you should probably get a replacement battery.

1. Be aware of the battery's age
2. Check the availability of the genuine battery from the manufacturer.

Then take a decision.

Comment: Thanks, batteries are a mystery.